# How do I remove a view controller from the memory?

Tags: swift, view

I am using segues to present a new view controller. I have a 1 button that goes to VC 2. I am using this code:

```
func jumpToVC() {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        [unowned self] in
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("whatVC", sender: self)
    }
}
```

However the VC will not remove itself from the memory. How can I achieve this? I am presenting my views modally.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Like this not the best practice where you will remove the presentingViewController from memory.

Comment: I read that code from a solution elsewhere here. I just want that if the user presses a button, it goes to another vc, and dismisses the old vc. That is all.

Comment: Is this VC your rootViewController?

Comment: So you have a `UIViewController` __A__ and a segue to present another `UIViewController` __B__. After the segue is executed you want to remove __A__ from memory right? This is against to how UIKit works. The real question is: why do you want to do that?

Comment: I think I am just totally lost here. I read so many tutorials, I just messed up. Forget about the segues and all. Lets say I have 2 VC's. VC 1 has 1 button on it. When the user presses button 1, I want to show VC 2. When VC 2 is shown up, I want that VC 1 will be removed.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you got a little bit lost here. What you want is a segue that will cause you to change `UIViewController` object to another one. You don't need to delete the first `UIViewController` and it's against practice in Swift.

From what I guess, you're just starting your journey with Swift and I know how confusing it might be. Therefore, I recommend you try this tutorial: https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/developing-ios-9-apps-swift/id1104579961

I've recently learnt from that and it's the best thing I've found.

Let me know if you have any more questions and whether I can help you somehow.

Comment: Yes I know, I read a lot of tutorials like this. I am just wondering if anyone can explain my problem in a few lines, not another tutorial...

Comment: But why do you want to delete it from memory?

Comment: Because it is using memory. But I am presenting it wrong. What code must I put inside the IBAction fund buttonPressed {} to correctly dismiss the current VC and present the other VC?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't do this in Swift, as Swift doesn't allow you to dynamically allocate memory (unlike C++). The only thing you can do is declare the instance as Optional and then set it to nil.